# Use set -x and export to a file

Tags: bash, bash4

Is there any way to export all the output of `set -x` to a file?
my exercise is to use `set -x` do some functions like `mkdir` and `touch`
and export all the output to a file.

Thanks

Comment: `bash -x` outputs stuff to standard error, so you could run a sub-shell and redirect its stderr to a file.

Comment: @Roey you could save everything you run via script -a session.log -- just run that one you login and you start the script/session. It will save each and every command and its output into the logfile specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ (set -x; echo hello) &> foo.txt

$ cat foo.txt
+ echo hello
hello
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/hulu.sh)